# Parameter to improve geth performances?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have setup a local node using geth and fast sync.

I use it in combination of ganache to simulate transaction after forking from mainnet. However, I am not satisfied with the performance. Only a few `eth_call` to my node (through ganache) can very fastly result in more than 1s to perform my whole simulation. I need my whole simulation to take less than 50ms, which I thought possible since everything is running locally.

All the calls are made through websockets. My node is running on a NVME SSD and Ryzen 7 processor. All the geth parameters are set to defaut.

Is there any thing I can do to speed up geth ? Might it be from the hardware or software ?